# Android - Copying item from one listview to another listview

Tags: java, android, listview, mobile, android-listview

I've been working on this Android project and have been struggling with it. I currently have two listviews, both displaying data.

I'm unsure how to copy an item from one listview to another when that item is clicked.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView mListView1, mListView2;

private String [] rock ={"The Beatles", "The Rolling Stones", "Jimi Hendrix", "Elvis Presley", "Pink Floyd", "AC/DC"};
private String [] pop ={"Michael Jackson", "Beyonce", "Rihanna", "Justin Bieber", "Lady Gaga", "Katy Perry"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mListView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    mListView2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);

    mListView1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, rock));
    mListView2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pop));

    ListUtils.setDynamicHeight(mListView1);
    ListUtils.setDynamicHeight(mListView2);
}


public static class ListUtils {
    public static void setDynamicHeight(ListView mListView) {
        ListAdapter mListAdapter = mListView.getAdapter();
        if (mListAdapter == null) {
            // when adapter is null
            return;
        }
        int height = 0;
        int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mListView.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        for (int i = 0; i < mListAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = mListAdapter.getView(i, null, mListView);
            listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            height += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mListView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = height + (mListView.getDividerHeight() * (mListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        mListView.setLayoutParams(params);
        mListView.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

}

and then my main.xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Rock" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="#B29090" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Pop" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="#4A9C67" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

For example, when The Beatles is clicked on I would like it to be copied into the pop listview.

I have tried using this (below example found on another answer) but it would not work as it said the listview didn't have an add() or notifyDataSetChange() method.

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(this);

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    datasListView2.add(valuesListView1.get(position));
    listView2.notifyDataSetChange();
}
```

Comment: Im not sure but maybe you should do adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

So you have 2 lists, rock and pop right? and you want when you click on an item on the first listView (The one that displays the rock list) to copy that item to the second listView (The one that displays the pop list).

You just need to add that item to the "pop" list then call notifyDataSetChange() on the listview adapter.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    pop.add(rock.get(position));
    mListView2.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChange();
}
```

That should be pretty easy but maybe you dont want to modify that "pop" list and only the list that is shown in the adapter?

In that case you should store a copy of the array inside each of the adapters, so you will be able to modify it without affecting the main list.

To achieve that you will need to subclass the adapter you are using.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String [] rock ={"The Beatles", "The Rolling Stones", "Jimi Hendrix", "Elvis Presley", "Pink Floyd", "AC/DC"};
private String [] pop ={"Michael Jackson", "Beyonce", "Rihanna", "Justin Bieber", "Lady Gaga", "Katy Perry"};

private List rocklist = new ArrayList();
private List poplist = new ArrayList();
private ArrayAdapter adapterRock;
private ArrayAdapter adapterPop;
private ListView mListView1;
private ListView mListView2;

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    for(String a : rock){
        rocklist.add(a);
    }
    for (String b : pop){
        poplist.add(b);
    }

    mListView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    mListView2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    adapterRock =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, rocklist);
    mListView1.setAdapter(adapterRock);
    adapterPop = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, poplist);
    mListView2.setAdapter(adapterPop);

    mListView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            poplist.add(rocklist.get(position));
            adapterPop.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Tried this but it didn't seem to do anything different when I clicked on an item. Both listviews stayed the same

Comment: If arrayList is of different model, how can we move component from one type to another.